# Getting predicted values with confidence interval on Negative binomial regression with fixed effects

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm using the `R` `fixest` package to fit a negative binomial regression model with three fixed effect variables. The function I am using is `fenebin()`.
I want to draw a plot with my predicted values and a confidence interval similarly to this post: https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2018/12/10/confidence-intervals-for-glms/

Since the `fixest` package provides the [standard-error of the predicted value with GLM models](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/reference/predict.fixest.html), how can I get these standard errors?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the current version (0.11.1) of `fixest` doesn't seem to implement the computation of prediction standard errors for GLMs. Although this has not been stated on the help page of predict (`?predict.fixest`), if you try to compute these standard errors using a GLM, you'll get an error message.

Here is an `R` demonstration of this using Poisson regression.

```
library(fixest)
library(dplyr)
wasp <- read.csv('darlingtonia.csv', sep = ",", skip = 1)
wasp <- mutate(wasp, lvisited = as.logical(visited))

res = feglm(lvisited ~ leafHeight, wasp, "poisson")
obs_fe = predict(res)

# generate fake new data
ndata <- with(wasp, data_frame(leafHeight = seq(min(leafHeight),
                                                max(leafHeight),
                                                length = 100)))
# try to extrat prediction se
ndata <- add_column(ndata,
                    wrong_se = predict(object = res,
                                       newdata = ndata,
                                       type = 'response',
                                       se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit)

Error in predict.fixest(object = res, newdata = ndata, type = "response",  : 
  The standard-error of the prediction is currently only available for OLS models, sorry.
```